# Can I give priority to a particular process to write to NFS disk?

Tags: linux, process, nfs

I have two processes running on a linux machine. Process 1 is a multi-threaded process where each thread is reading big files (100MB to 1GB) from local disk and writing them on a NFS disk. There are 8 threads active on process 1. My process 2 is doing some computation and is writing few KBs of data on NFS disk frequently. Problem I am observing is that some time process 1 gets stuck for multiple seconds to multiple minutes in its Write operation on NFS disk. I am looking for a solution where I can give priority to NFS operations of process 1 over process 2. Some what similar solution which we have for giving CPU priority using nice.

Nfs system is live on another server. Process 2 is not stuck due to swap usage. As per my understanding issue is happening because process 1 is chocking the machine network connection and nfs server. So I want to prioritize the process 2 for nfs access over process 1.

Comment: A good question, but I don't think there is enough information here to make an informed comment (or answer). Does the NFS system "live" on another server? How active is that server? "Stuck for multiple seconds" is one thing, but "stuck for multiple minutes" is another. Does `iostat` /`vmstat` show anything interesting, including activity for `swap` space? See https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/iostat-vmstat-mpstat-examples/ . Do you have an NFS skilled tech to confirm there are no software/hardware/network issues affecting you?

Comment: Please don't reply in comments, but improve your Q with any data you can share about activity on your system. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, nfs system is live on another server. No, issue is not due to swap usage. As per my understanding issue is happening because process 1 is chocking the machine network connection and nfs server. So I want to prioritize the process 2 for nfs access over process 1.

Comment: Can't help, but I think you'll need to edit your Q to include the facts of "your understanding" (what are the observations?). Good luck.